# Potential difference due to point charges

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential, voltage

Now, there are [many](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/19-3-electrical-potential-due-to-a-point-charge/) [sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential#Electric_potential_due_to_a_point_charge) saying the potential difference created by a point source is given by
\begin{equation}
V=\dfrac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\dfrac{Q}{r}
\end{equation}
Which looks like it's just doing $\Delta V=Ed$. However, upon closer examination, this cannot be the case, because $\Delta V=Ed$ is used when there is a uniform electric field, such that $E$ is a constant. But here $E$ is obviously not a constant, as it varies with distance. So I solved the differential equation, which does give me a similar result, namely
\begin{align}
\dfrac{dV}{dr}&=-E\\
V&=-\int \dfrac{kQ}{r^2}\ dr\\
&=\dfrac{kQ}{r}+C
\end{align}
And obviously, in order to get to the equation as required, I would just need to make the bounds from infinity to $r$, namely
\begin{align}
V=\left[\dfrac{kQ}{r}\right]^{r}_{\infty}=\dfrac{kQ}{r}
\end{align}
Now, althought I have gotten the process, I do a have a few questions about it.

1. Is there any intuitive explanation on why the differential equation has a negative sign?
2. The equation we're generally familiar with is $\Delta V=-Ed$. Why doesn't the equation derived above have the negative sign?

P.S. I seem to have a basic grasp on question 2., namely it deals with change in potential instead of pure potential. It would still be appreciated if one could elaboarte on this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative of the electric potential is negative as the direction of increasing electric potential is opposite to the direction of the electric field. Let us take a positive source charge. The direction of the electric field due to the source charge is radially outwards. The electric potential at a point is defined as the work done in bringing a unit positive test charge from infinity to that point. Clearly, we are bringing the unit positive charge against the direction of the electric field.

From the definition of electric potential

$$dV = \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{s} $$

Here $\vec{E} = E \ \hat{r}$ and $d\vec{s} = -dr \ \hat{r}$

$$dV = -E \ dr$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{dV}{dr} = -E$$

Note that $E$ here is the magnitude of the electric field.

Comment: Hmm I think this sort of explains the second part as well, would it be that there's a negative sign in V=-Ed because here increasing distance porportionally decreases the potential.

Comment: Proportionality is not dictated by the sign. Two quantities A and B are inversely proportional if A = c/B, where c is a constant.

Comment: Yes I understand, what I meant is that if $\Delta V=Ed$, then the potential increases with further distance, which is not the case, so we put a negative at the front so that the potential decreases with increasing distance. Is that how the intuition goes?

Comment: No. The electric field isn't a constant. And even if it were the case, the magnitude of the potential would become more negative with the increasing distance. The relationship between V and r is obtained from the expression for electric potential i.e. $V = kQ/r$

Comment: ok ok, one last question and I'll accept the answer.. How do we go from $V=kQ/r$ to $\Delta V=-Ed$? Where is the negative sign introduced

Comment: The formula you stated is valid for constant electric field e.g in parallel plate capacitors. The sign and the formula are obtained simply by integration of the expression $dV = -E.dr$. $E$ is a constant and $dr$ is integrated between the limits of integration which simply evaluates to $d$.